# C# Get all words from text file starting with X

Tags: c#, text, extract

I have a text file that looks like this:

> ('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXX', 'User1', 'Germany', 73677, 0, 0, 105, 151, 105, '2015-09-05'),
>    ('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXX', 'User2', 'Belgium', 64005, 3, 100, 161, 277, 161, '2015-11-08'),
>   ('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXX', 'User3', 'Denmark', 52226, 0, 0, 84, 146, 84, '2015-11-05'),
>   ('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXXX', 'User4', 'Denmark', 48300, 0, 0, 98, 291, 98, '2015-09-29'),
>   ('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXX', 'User5', 'Denmark', 47817, 4, 1000, 104, 272, 104, '2015-11-08'),

How do I extract the "STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXX" and nothing else to a whole new file? I have 250 users.

I'm very new to programming, but I've tried a few things, nothing has worked though.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post an example of some code you have tried so far so that we can better assist.

Comment: Use `string.Split` method , first split by `Environment.NewLine`, then split every token from the resulting array by `"',"` - for every split token get the first sub token and remove first two letters and you have it. The other option would be to use Regular Expression which I'm not a fan of so someone else can give you an idea for that, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"\('(?'steam'[^']*)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["steam"]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thank you! I added using StreamWriter just before the foreach and it worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
 List<string> formattedList = new List<string>();

        //read from .txt file
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Source path.txt"))
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            //get index of second occurance of the ' char.
            int length = line.IndexOf("'", 2); 

            //start 2 indexes in and return the substring until second 
            //occurance of ' char
            string formattedLine = line.Substring(2, length);
            formattedList.Add(formattedLine);

        }

        //write to .txt file
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Destination Path.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var line in formattedList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

For more info read
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the most elegant solution but it works!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text =
@"('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXX', 'User1', 'Germany', 73677, 0, 0, 105, 151, 105, '2015-09-05'),
('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXX', 'User2', 'Belgium', 64005, 3, 100, 161, 277, 161, '2015-11-08'),
('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXX', 'User3', 'Denmark', 52226, 0, 0, 84, 146, 84, '2015-11-05'),
('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXXX', 'User4', 'Denmark', 48300, 0, 0, 98, 291, 98, '2015-09-29'),
('STEAM_1:0:XXXXXXXX', 'User5', 'Denmark', 47817, 4, 1000, 104, 272, 104, '2015-11-08'),";

        var split = text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string line in split)
        {
            var firstCommer = line.IndexOf(",");

            sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(2, firstCommer - 3));
        }


        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\out.txt", sb.ToString());
    }
```